# Using AspectJ on JSP

Tags: jsp, ajdt

I am trying to use AspectJ on my java beans, which I will use eventually in a JSP.

Can anybody lead me to do this? Because I really cannot succeed, even though the thing seems to be trivial!

Also, the tomcat is telling me org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please expand a bit. How did you configure AspectJ? Load time weaving or compile time weaving? Which jars are on the classpath?

Comment: I am using compile time weaving.

I am also adding the aspectjrt.jar to the build path

Comment: hey i managed to solve it!

followed this tutorial http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5401681

it is important for the newbies (like me), you have to declare the aop.xml, by right-clicking on your project drop-down the AspectJ-Build and Add the aop.xml

also, in your class path (of the Run Configuration) you have to add the aspectjrt.jar

this should work!

thanks Kees de Kooter for your interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i managed to solve it!

followed this tutorial forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5401681/

… it is important for the newbies (like me), you have to declare the aop.xml, by right-clicking on your project drop-down the AspectJ-Build and Add the aop.xml also, in your class path (of the Run Configuration) you have to add the aspectjrt.jar this should work!